# representing a custom view controller in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i have a Root View Controller initialised to load in the application's delegate didLaunchWithOptions method. I started the project without storyboards. Now, how can i represent this "Root view controller" in a storyboard so that i can drag and drop interface objects ?

I want the root view controller class to be shown in the storyboard. is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes . It is and its easy . Select your appropriate Object (ViewController) and drag and drop it in storyBoard. I mean If your rootviewcontroller is a UIViewController then select it object as UIViewController. If it a TableViewVontroller then drang and drop an Object of UITableviewcontroller

Once you are done with this connect your storyboard with the class by selecting the Object and go to Identity Inspector (Right Pane on Storyboard with 3 tab which looks like a newspapaer) If you are not able to find it go to view -> utilities ->show identity inspector.

In that there is an option to specify class. Mention you rootviewcontroller class name and that all .

Comment: ok i did that but its not quite working ... the "root view controller" is a UITableViewController object and it has a title bar right, but in the storyboard it is a generic object that i have dragged and dropped and then set its class to "root view controller", the title bar is not there, and if i make any changes to the one in storyboard and run it, its not reflecting the changes.. why is that ?

Comment: Ok. I don't know exactly what your header file looks like . But I assume the following cases :

1)If your UITableViewController is a property in you appdelegate(or and other class) then you need to connect your storyboard object via IBOutlet for the effect to take place. 
2)If you have a Wrapper around UITableviewcontroller (If you are subclassing) then provide your subclassed name in the identity inspector for the effects to take place.

Comment: And make sure that objects in storyboard and Connecting objects are matching . I dont know what you mean by a generic Object

Comment: There is one very interesting tutorial to guid you through storyboard (with video) have a look to check If you have gone through all the steps .  http://codingandcoffee.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/iphone-tutorial-one-introduction-to-storyboarding/

Answer (score 0):

You just drag a `UIViewController` to your storyboard and set its class to `RootViewController`. Also set it to be the initial view controller (there should be a checkbox).

Then you can drag and drop whatever you want onto it.